# Dynamic memory allocation of structure and passing it in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, malloc

I have some confusion with the pointers and structures. Below is the small code snippet, Please help me to corret it. How do I pass dynamically allocated struct in a function?

```
struct xxx{
    int x1;
    int x2'
}


struct xxx function1(struct xxx *x)
{
    struct xxx *B;
    B = (struct xxx*)malloc(sizeof(struct xxx));
  
    return B    
}


int main()
{
    struct xxx *A;
    struct xxx *B;
    A = (struct xxx*)malloc(sizeof(struct xxx));
    B = (struct xxx*)malloc(sizeof(struct xxx));
    
    B = function(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct xxx{
    int x1;
    int x2'
}` does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code, and performed a bit of cleanup as it would not compile, and then added in some sample code to give the custom function some meaning.  Following is a sample code snippet expanding upon the functionality of your structure program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct xxx{
    int x1;
    int x2;
};          /* You were missing the semicolon */


struct xxx* function1(struct xxx* x)    /* Needed the pointer reference for the return value */
{
    struct xxx *B;
    B = (struct xxx*)malloc(sizeof(struct xxx));

    B->x1 = x->x1 + 1;      /* Do something to initialize the new structure using data from the input strucuter */
    B->x2 = x->x2 + 1;

    return B;
}


int main()
{
    struct xxx *A;
    struct xxx *B;
    A = (struct xxx*)malloc(sizeof(struct xxx));
    A->x1 = 234;
    A->x2 = 65535;
    //B = (struct xxx*)malloc(sizeof(struct xxx));  /* No need to do this as will get an allocated structure from the function */

    B = function1(A);

    printf("A structure values: x1: %d, x2: %d\n", A->x1, A->x2);
    printf("B structure values: x1: %d, x2: %d\n", B->x1, B->x2);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some key points.

- First, I added in a missing semicolon at the end of your structure definition.  I don't know if that was just missed in submitting your code example, but it is needed.  Otherwise the program won't compile.
- Next, since function1 is supposed to return a structure pointer, the signature was corrected from "struct xxx function1(struct xxx* x)" to "struct xxx* function1(struct xxx* x)"
- The code within the function was fine, but was not really doing anything, so some sample code was added to provide a usage for the input structure (xxx) providing some data to the structure that is created within the function.
- In the main function, the allocation memory for pointer "B" is deactivated, since this pointer will be updated with the structure and its allocated memory from the function call.  If that line were left active, you would in effect have removed the reference to the initial allocated memory for pointer "B" causing a memory leak.

So with that in mind, following is the sample output at the terminal when running this example.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/StructureB/bin/Release$ ./StructureB 
A structure values: x1: 234, x2: 65535
B structure values: x1: 235, x2: 65536
```

Hopefully, that provides some additional insight into defining and using structures.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing some of my doubts with clear explanation. 

Best regards,
Nikhil Ganapathy